# Question about modelling a railway system

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I am currently working on a task, where I have to build a railway simulation project in java (university project).

> There are three types of rolling stock: *wagon*, *locomotive* and *multiple unit*.
>
> All types of the rolling stock have a name and a length.
>
> In addition, there are also three types of wagons and locomotives.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx9w1.png) is a simple UML diagram that I created.

Now, I still have to implement this "feature":

> *"The multiple unit ID is composed according to the same rules as for locomotives. For this reason, locomotives and multiple units share the same ID space. A multiple unit has a special type of coupling and can therefore only be composed with the same series of multiple units"*

What is the best way to use the same ID space for locomotives and multiple units?

Is this a good model or should I use interfaces instead? I would appreciate feedback and tips. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot access your link, company firewall....however I would suggest you create a base class that has all the common features in that you require for all your types, then derive a unique type class from the base for each, containing only the unique properties.

Comment: But I don't have any code yet and I can't post in @codereview without lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to use the same ID space for locomotives and multiple units?

Doesn't matter, as long as it is unique. Just use a serial number or, if you want to have one that isn't tied to a single counter, use a fully random one (of 128 bits or more). Why not use a [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) while you're at it.

One question you should ask yourself is: is this ID going to be used on the wagons? If so, a short, statically serial number (or string) certainly makes more sense. Probably there will be some *registration body* so in that case you have your centralized counter right there. **Never forget to check if your model matches the real world!**

It makes some sense to prefix the ID with the type of transport, although in that case I think it is not really using the same space anymore.

> Is this a good model or should I use interfaces instead? I would appreciate feedback and tips.

EDIT: WRONG, I ASSUMED ALL ROLLING STOCK WOULD HAVE AN ID!!!

No, this is fine, you have operations on the ID after all. And you're probably going to add other functionality that it similar for all child classes to the rolling stock. Note that many environments have methods to *extract* an interface and replace the existing references to that interface. Refactoring is not something you *want* to do, but it is there when you need it.

EDIT:

If you have an ID just for locomotives and rolling stock then there are two options. Probably best is to insert an intermediate abstract class that defines an `IdentifyableRollingStock` intermediate class. There are other options out there such as creating an optional ID, or using a decorator pattern. It is a bit strange if wagons cannot be identified though, in NL I'm  pretty sure that all rolling stock is identifiable.

I'm just left wondering if all rolling stock really has a *name*. I can see some cargo wagons just having a number. That's another real world check right there.

---

OT

> A multiple unit has a special type of coupling and can therefore only be composed with the same series of multiple units"

The person who wrote that should be shot into orbit. Well be nice and make it the ISS. Going round and round and round...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! This ID is not going to be used on the wagons. The ID of the multiple units (or trainsets) and locomotives consist of a series and a name (<series>-<name>). For example "T30-34K" would be a possible name. How can I use the same ID-space for both classes now?

Comment: Looks like a normal string to me. If you put it in the inherited field and make it a `String` you're already there if you ask me. If you have other type requirements you must make them explicit. You probably need a class to generate these kind of ID's. Funny, that definitely looks like a number that you would put on wagons. It would seriously limit the amount of rolling stock though.

Comment: Made a change, edited answer.

Comment: Actually all rolling stock have an Id. Wagons have a unique Id (positive integers in ascending order). Locomotive and Multiple unit (trainsets) share the ID-Space and the ID structure is „<series>-<name>“. The name is inherited by RollingStock and I added the attribute „series“ to both Locomotive and MultipleUnit. Is the best option to create another class that stores the id in a map or am I still on the wrong track? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I'd not go overboard with maps. You just need to make sure that you don't get the same name within a series...